# Proving an equality for contraction of complex Ricci tensor on a Kähler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M, g)$ be a Kähler manifold and $\rm{Ric}$ be its Ricci tensor defined on $T_\mathbb{C}M$ as the $\mathbb C$-bilinear extension of the usual Ricci tensor on $TM$.
I want to prove that in any local frame $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n, \bar{Z_1},\ldots,\bar{Z_n})$ of $T_\mathbb{C}M$ we have that
$$   g^{\ell, \bar{\nu}}  \mathrm{Ric}_{\mu, \bar{\nu}} =R^\ell_{ \alpha, \bar{\alpha}, \mu} .$$
I've seen the LHS of the desired inequality often written as $R^\ell_\mu$. So far, I've tried the following: using that $\mathrm{Ric}_{\mu, \bar{\nu}} =  g^{\alpha, \bar{\beta}} \mathrm{Rm}_{\alpha, \bar{\beta}, \mu, \bar{\nu}}$ and $\mathrm{Rm}_{\alpha, \bar{\beta}, j, \bar{k}}=g_{\mu, \bar{\beta}}R^\mu_{j, \bar{k}, \alpha}$, we arrive at
$$    g^{\ell, \bar{\nu}}  \mathrm{Ric}_{\mu, \bar{\nu}} =g^{\ell, \bar{\nu}}  g^{\alpha, \bar{\beta}} \mathrm{Rm}_{\alpha, \bar{\beta}, \mu, \bar{\nu}}=  g^{\alpha, \bar{\beta}} \Big(g^{\ell, \bar{\nu}}  \mathrm{Rm}_{\alpha, \bar{\beta}, \mu, \bar{\nu}}\Big)  =g^{\alpha, \bar{\beta}} R^\ell_{ \alpha, \bar{\beta}, \mu }. $$
However, I can't see how to continue from here.

I must add that I'm using standard conventions here, namely: $   R(X,Y)Z=\nabla _{X}\nabla _{Y}Z-\nabla _{Y}\nabla _{X}Z-\nabla _{[X,Y]}Z $ where $X, Y, Z$ are complex vector fields, $\nabla$ is the complex $\mathbb C$-bilinear extension of the Levi-Civita connection of $(M, g)$ and $\mathrm{Rm}(X, Y, Z, W)=g(R(X, Y)Z, W)$. Any help is appreciated, regards.

Comment: A note on notation: are you sure about those commas in the indices? Usually a comma denotes a partial derivative along that coordinate. Anyway, it seems to me that the equality is true (taking a sum on the repeated index $\alpha$), in a system of normal Kähler coordinates. It seems strange that the equality should be true for general frames, also given the fact that on the right hand side the contracted indices are both lower indices.